# Getting NullPointerException using spark-csv with DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

Running through the [spark-csv README](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/README.md) there's sample Java code like this    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;

```
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
StructType customSchema = new StructType(
    new StructField("year", IntegerType, true), 
    new StructField("make", StringType, true),
    new StructField("model", StringType, true),
    new StructField("comment", StringType, true),
    new StructField("blank", StringType, true));

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("cars.csv");

df.select("year", "model").write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("newcars.csv");
```

It didn't compile out of the box, so with some wrangling I got it to compile with changing the incorrect `FooType` syntax to `DataTypes.FooType` and passing the StructFields as a `new StructField[]`; the compiler requested a fourth argument for `metadata` in the constructor of `StructField` but I had trouble finding documentation on what it means (javadocs describe its use cases, but not really how to decide what to pass in during StructField construction). With the following code, it now runs until any side-effect method like `collect()`:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

// Read features.
System.out.println("Reading features from " + args[0]);
StructType featuresSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
    new StructField("case_id", DataTypes.StringType, false, null), 
    new StructField("foo", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, null)
});
DataFrame features = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .schema(featuresSchema)
    .load(args[0]);
for (Row r : features.collect()) {
  System.out.println("Row: " + r);
}
```

I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.hashCode(namedExpressions.scala:202)
  at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.hash(ScalaRunTime.scala:210)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.elemHashCode(HashSet.scala:65)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.computeHash(HashSet.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.$plus(HashSet.scala:56)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.$plus(HashSet.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set4.$plus(Set.scala:127)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set4.$plus(Set.scala:121)
  at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.$plus$eq(SetBuilder.scala:24)
  at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.$plus$eq(SetBuilder.scala:22)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
  at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
  at scala.collection.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:47)
  at scala.collection.SetLike$class.map(SetLike.scala:93)
  at scala.collection.AbstractSet.map(Set.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet.foreach(AttributeSet.scala:114)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.size(TraversableOnce.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeSet.size(AttributeSet.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:282)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:926)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:924)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:930)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:930)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)
...
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 10):

It seems the README is very outdated, and needs some significant editing for the Java example. I tracked down the actual [JIRA which added the metadata field](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3569) and it points at the usage of a default `Map.empty` value for Scala cases, and whoever wrote the documentation must have just translated the Scala directly to Java despite the lack of the same default value for the input parameter.

In the [1.5 branch of SparkSQL's code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.5/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/namedExpressions.scala#L211) we can see that it references `metadata.hashCode()` without checking, which is what's causing the `NullPointerException`. The existence of the [Metadata.empty()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata.html#empty()) method combined with the discussions about using empty maps as default in Scala seem to imply the correct implementation is to go ahead and pass `Metadata.empty()` if you don't care about it. The revised example should be:

```
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
StructType customSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
    new StructField("year", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()), 
    new StructField("make", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("model", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("comment", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("blank", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
});

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("cars.csv");

df.select("year", "model").write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("newcars.csv");
```

Comment: Sent a [pull request to spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/commit/c684717dc2aefd3b50ae2a283bffd39ffbb3ed7a) to fix the documentation

Comment: I think you need to change your answer from .option("inferSchema", "true") to .option("customSchema", "true")

Comment: Ah indeed you're right, good catch, I was only paying attention to the lines specifying the customSchema definition when trying to make the minimal change to the upstream example. Sent another [pull request](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/pull/229) to fix this in the documentation and edited the answer to match.

Answer (score 3):

Even i'm getting same exception.
I fixed it by providing the metadata.

so change the code like

```
StructType customSchema = new StructType(
new StructField("year", IntegerType, true,Metadata.empty()), 
new StructField("make", StringType, true,Metadata.empty()),
new StructField("model", StringType, true,Metadata.empty()),
new StructField("comment", StringType, true,Metadata.empty()),
new StructField("blank", StringType, true,Metadata.empty()));
```

this will fix the issue